# Looking for Celeyrette's PhD thesis, "Fibrations et extensions de Kan"

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

In his topos theory textbook, Johnstone cites the following reference:

> [17] J. Celeyrette "Fibrations et extensions de Kan". These de 3$^\rm{e}$ cycle, Université Paris-Nord 1974.

Is there some online source where one can find this thesis?

Comment: Do you mean the Baby Elephant, or the Elephant itself? If the former, I could imagine that the information was a bit wobbly. If the latter, I'm quite surprised, given Dmitri's answer.

Comment: @DavidRoberts It's from the Baby Elephant. (It seems the Elephant doesn't cite either of the two theses in Dmitri's answer, actually)

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Johnstone didn't want to cite anything that wasn't actually published (i.e. in a Journal or as a book) in the Elephant, because there were so many unpublished documents/lecture notes/preprints/manuscripts on topos theory in the 70s and to a lesser extent in the 80s, it was unreasonable to cite such works in a reference book, and not miss something and offend someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two theses by Jean Celeyrette indexed by various libraries:

[Theoreme de Kan dans un topos](https://www.worldcat.org/title/theoreme-de-kan-dans-un-topos/oclc/25404008) (Lille, 1974).

Catégories internes et fibrations ; Cohomologie de Gel'fand-Fuks (Paris-Nord, 1975).
Library records:
[1](https://www.worldcat.org/title/categories-internes-et-fibrations/oclc/3878866), [2](https://www.worldcat.org/title/categories-internes-et-fibrations/oclc/251638087),
[3](https://www.worldcat.org/title/categories-internes-et-fibrations-cohomologie-de-gelfand-fuks/oclc/602698161).

If the bibliographic records are accurate,
this would seem to suggest that Johnstone's citation may be inaccurate
(assuming one can only produce one thesis per year)
and you really want one of the two theses listed above.

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri!

Comment: Here's the second thesis, by the way: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10wpCxiaCg50Gr37IArFD1TGIJaeYar1q/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: @Emily: Thanks a lot, now available on the nLab here: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/list+of+theses+in+category+theory

Comment: Hey, thank *you*, Dmitri, having an [nLab link for the thesis PDF](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/celeyrette-thesis-1975.pdf) is much better than a Google Drive one!